# Initializer List for Derived Class

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, polymorphism, initializer-list

I want to have a derived class which has a default constructor that initializes the inheirited members.

Why can I do this

```
class base{
protected:
 int data;
};

class derived: public base{
public:
 derived(){ //note
  data = 42;
 }
};

int main(){
 derived d();
}
```

But not this

```
class base{
protected:
 int data;
};

class derived: public base{
public:
 derived(): //note
  data(42){}
};

int main(){
 derived d();
}
```

`error: class ‘derived’ does not have any field named ‘data’`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An object can only be initialized once. (The exception is if you initialize it and then destroy it; then you can initialize it again later.)

If you could do what you're trying to do, then `base::data` could potentially be initialized twice. Some constructor of `base` might initialize it (although in your particular case it doesn't) and then the `derived` constructor would be initializing it, potentially for a second time. To prevent this, the language only allows a constructor to initialize its own class's members.

Initialization is distinct from assignment. Assigning to `data` is no problem: you can only initialize `data` once but you can assign to it as many times as you want.

You might want to write a constructor for `base` that takes a value for `data`.

```
class base{
protected:
 int data;
 base(int data): data(data) {}
};

class derived: public base{
public:
 derived(): base(42) {}
};

int main(){
 derived d{}; // note: use curly braces to avoid declaring a function
}
```

Comment: I would hasten to clarify for readers who are new(er) to OOP - an object is (roughly) an instance of a class, so while you can have multiple objects of the same class, each of those objects can only be initialized once.

Comment: @JasonMc92 An `int` is also an object in C++. An object is a region of storage.

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm just putting that note of clarification. Way back when I learned OOP, I used to get confused between "class" and "object", so I'm just lending a little extra clarity for those groups. :D

Answer (score 2):

You need a base class constructor for this job. You can look for more explanation here -

[Initialize parent's protected members with initialization list (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290733/initialize-parents-protected-members-with-initialization-list-c)