# Copy constructor doesn't recognize inherited members

Tags: c++, inheritance, copy-constructor, sdl-2

I have two classes:

```
class entity {
public:
  SDL_Rect pos;
  float x;
  float y;

  std::string spriteFile;
  SDL_Surface * spriteHandle;
  int rePos (int newX, int newY);
  int move (float deltaX, float deltaY, bool check); // Move x & y the specified amounts, also moving pos.x and pos.y for every integer increase of x or y
  int display (SDL_Surface * screenSurface); //Use SDL_BlipSurface to blip the image to the screen
  int loadImage (SDL_PixelFormat * format); //Load the image using the spriteFile string and optimize it using the SDL_PixelFormat of the Screen

  entity (std::string file, int w, int h);
  entity () {};
  ~entity () { SDL_FreeSurface(spriteHandle);}

  entity (const entity &old) : pos(old.pos), x(old.x), y(old.y), spriteFile(old.spriteFile) {
  spriteHandle = new SDL_Surface(*spriteHandle);
  }

};

class multiEntity: public entity {
  /*
    Use multiEntity rather than entity when multiple images need to be blipped to different
    positions.
   */
private:
  static std::vector<stringBoolPair> deconstructed;
public:
  std::string entType;
  multiEntity (std::string file, int w, int h, std::string enttype) {
    entity(file, w, h);
    entType = enttype;
    bool found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < deconstructed.size(); i++) {
      found = (enttype == deconstructed[i].str);
    }
    if (found) deconstructed.emplace_back(enttype, false);
  }

  multiEntity (const multiEntity& old) :
    spriteFile(old.spriteFile),
    x(old.x),
    y(old.y),
    spriteHandle(old.spriteHandle),
    pos(old.pos),
    entType(old.entType) {}
    ~multiEntity () {
    for (int i = 0; i < deconstructed.size(); i++) {
      if (deconstructed[i].str == entType) {
    SDL_FreeSurface(spriteHandle);
    deconstructed[i].Bool = true;
      }
    }
  }

  multiEntity& operator= (const multiEntity& old) {
    spriteFile = old.spriteFile;
    pos = old.pos;
    x = old.x;
    y = old.y;
    entType = old.entType;
    spriteHandle = old.spriteHandle;
    return *this;
  }
};
```

When I attempt to compile the code that includes this, I get an error messages saying that `class multiEntity does not have any field named 'pos'`. This happens for all of the variables in the copy constructor except for `entType`.
What I'm attempting to do is have a vector of `entity`s using the same SDL_Surface. Therefore, I felt that I should create a separate class where every object with the same `entType` has the same value for `spriteHandle`. This is supposed to point to the same image, which is most useful when I have 75 instances of an image that I'm trying to blip to the screen. I want to use vector's constructor layout so that the information is copied over rather than creating a new pointer each time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initialize parent's protected members with initialization list (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290733/initialize-parents-protected-members-with-initialization-list-c)

Comment: You didn't need to post all of this code to point out the issue you're having.  [An example](http://ideone.com/XAu2el)

Comment: Thanks @PaulMcKenzie. I'll try to remember that and be more descriptive in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't initialize the base class's members in derived class's copy constructor; they should be initialized via base class's copy constructor. You should just invoke it in member initalizer list:

```
multiEntity (const multiEntity& old) :
    entity(old),         // initialize entity's members via entity::entity(const entity&)
    entType(old.entType) // initialize multiEntity's member entType 
{}
```

If the behavior of copy constructor of the base class is not what you want, you can do some assignment in the constructor body of the derived class, e.g.

```
multiEntity (const multiEntity& old) :
                         // nothing specified, same as write entity() here
                         // entity's members will be initialized via entity::entity()
    entType(old.entType) // initialize multiEntity's member entType 
{
    // perform assignment here
    spriteFile = old.spriteFile;
    x = old.x;
    y = old.y;
    spriteHandle = old.spriteHandle;
    pos = old.pos;
}
```

Comment: How then would I insure that the SDL_Surface is a shallow copy? I want it to copy the data in the parent class, but only copy the address in the child class.

Comment: @BobPaw Answer revised.