# C++ Q: Illegal member initialization trying to set base class member in derived

Tags: c++, c++17

EDITED: Removed the Base class being a template class, as this has no bearing on the issue as others have pointed out to me.

It has been a while since working with basic C++ concepts, and specifically the nuances of member initialization lists.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base() {}

protected:
    int m_Value;
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    Derived() :
    Base(),
    m_Value(-1)
    {
        m_Value = -1;
    };
};
```

Why am I getting (in VS2019 using C++ v17) an error C2614 "illegal member initialization: 'm_value'is not a base or member" for m_Value(-1) in the Derived constructor member initialization list, however explicitly setting it within the body of the Derived ctor is ok?

Thanks!
David

Comment: Try to remove the template part and you will see the same error. m_Value is base class member variable, so it should be initialized in base constructor. Or you may initialize it in the body of derived constructor. Just remove `m_Value(-1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with templates. A derived class cannot invoke the constructors of the base class's members directly. You must use the base class's constructor to initialize the base class's members.

This is because the base class has already initialized its members by the time the derived class is initialized.

```cpp
class Base
{
public:
    Base(int value) : m_Value(value) {}

protected:
    int m_Value;
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    Derived() :
    Base(-1)
    {
    };
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the untangling.

Comment: Thanks for the key issue which logically makes sense: the base class is already initialized. I saw a comment above from Jens (since deleted) who pointed me to the link StackOverflow now directs me to - which I didn't initially find - which describes the rationale in greater detail here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290733/initialize-parents-protected-members-with-initialization-list-c